# JQuery getting JSON.parse: unexpected character

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am getting the following error:

200

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

I have checked my JSON in firebug and it says the following:

```
jquery-1.8.3.js (line 2)
POST http://localhost:1579/Comets/Progress/4c691777-2a9f-42ca-8421-d076ab4d0450/1

200 OK    
JSON     
Sort by key     
MsgId          "4c691777-2a9f-42ca-8421-d076ab4d0450"    
Status         2    
CurrentServer  "10.10.143.4"
```

Which seems ok to me so i'm not sure where i am going wrong and why i am getting a error

My code is as folows:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function Progress() {
                            var msgId = $('textarea.msgId').val();
                            var status = $('textarea.status').val();
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: "/Comets/Progress/" + msgId + "/" + status,
                                success: function (data) {
                                    //update status
                                    alert("does this work");

                                },
                                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                    alert(xhr.status);
                                    alert(thrownError);
                                }
                            });
                        });
```

Controller:

```
  [JsonpFakeFilter]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public JsonResult Progress(string msgId, int status, String callback)
        {

            //todo need to put recursive function on here (status)

            //check the ip - has it changed
            string strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
            var ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
            var ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            var currentServer = ipAddress.ToString();

            var cometJson = new CometJson
                                {
                                    MsgId = msgId,
                                    Status = status,
                                    CurrentServer = currentServer
                                };

            //check what the status is if it is less than 4 we want to add one
            if (status <= 4)
            {
                status = status + 1;
                cometJson = new CometJson
                {
                    MsgId = msgId,
                    Status = status,
                    CurrentServer = currentServer
                };
                return Json(cometJson);
            }

            return Json(cometJson);
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show the JSON string that your server returns as seen in FireBug?

Comment: please try to log the Json Result maybe it's not right Json string.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Hi in firebug i m seeing MsgId
 

"fc91db57-b35e-4254-82f0-3defb9f4c079"

 
Status
 

2

 
CurrentServer
 

"10.10.143.4" is this not what you mean?

Comment: Have you tried replacing 

    data

by 

    data.d

Comment: @anna, no, I would like to see the raw JSON string returned by your server. What you have shown here is not JSON.

Comment: @writeToBhuwan it doesn't seem to like to data.d at all

Comment: in the success function write "console.log(data)" then post the result.

Comment: @ebramtharwat, I guess that if the server sends invalid JSON, the success callback won't even be invoked. The correct place to see that is in the Response tab.

Comment: yep it isn t going into the success function just trying to see the raw json string

Comment: @DarinDimitrov i think success dose not depend on the result JSON..the Request is what need the sent parameters to be correct JSON format.

Comment: @ebramtharwat, if the server sets `Content-Type: application/json` response header and then writes invalid JSON to the response the success callback will not be invoked and you will get an error message instead because when jQuery attempts to parse this invalid JSON string to a javascript object that needs to be passed to the success handler it will simply crash with the error message that the OP has shown here.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov  possible this..? callback_dc99fd712fff48d6a56e0d9db5465ac3({"MsgId":"b91949f4-a30e-4f3f-b6e8-f83fc40ada89","Status":2,"CurrentServer":"10.10.143.4"});

Comment: @DarinDimitrov you are right.

Comment: Alright, now that you have shown the raw response it is clear what the problem is. This is not JSON. This is JSONP. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server returns invalid JSON:

```
callback_dc99fd712fff48d6a56e0d9db5465ac3({"MsgId":"b91949f4-a30e-4f3f-b6e8-f83f‌​c40ada89","Status":2,"CurrentServer":"10.10.143.4"})
```

This is not JSON. This is [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) and is used from cross domain AJAX calls. In this case you are not making a cross domain AJAX call so you should remove the `callback_dc99fd712fff48d6a56e0d9db5465ac3` wrapper and return valid JSON:

```
{"MsgId":"b91949f4-a30e-4f3f-b6e8-f83f‌​c40ada89","Status":2,"CurrentServer":"10.10.143.4"}
```

I guess that the `[JsonpFakeFilter]` attribute that you have decorated your controller action with is responsible for wrapping the JSON result with this callback.

So get rid of it and make sure that your server returns valid JSON:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Progress(string msgId, int status)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks thats will make me go along the right route - i actually do need a jsonp as once live it will go cross domains but at least now i will be heading in the right direction